# Search pattern and grep part of line

Tags: awk

Grep pattern and select portion of a line after a matching patterns 41572: 90000: and 90002:

```
input

hyt : generation
str : 122344
stks : 9000233
dhy : 9000aaaa
sjyt : hist : hhh9000kkk
Count ch : 41572:47149-47999/2(14485-14910) 41584:47149-47999/2(14911-15449) 90000:47919-47999/2(15447-15477) 90002:47919-47999/2(15478-15418) 
drx : 12345
```

here the code used

```
awk '
{
  flag=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i ~ /41572/ || $i ~ /90000/ || $i ~ /90002/){
       flag=1
       printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)
    }
  }
}
!flag
'   Input_file
```

with the code above from Mr. RavinderSingh13, I got the following output

```
hyt : generation
str : 122344
stks : 9000233
dhy : 9000aaaa
sjyt : hist : hhh9000kkk
41572:47149-47999/2(14485-14910) 90000:47919-47999/2(15447-15477) 90002:47919-47999/2(15478-15418) 
drx : 12345
```

Would like to get the following output desired

```
hyt : generation
str : 122344
stks : 9000233
dhy : 9000aaaa
sjyt : hist : hhh9000kkk
Count ch : 41572:47149-47999/2(14485-14910) 90000:47919-47999/2(15447-15477) 90002:47919-47999/2(15478-15418) 
drx : 12345
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try to do code's fine tuning from your side too, as we all are here to learn on SO. There is nothing wrong in posting your effort in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that your actual Input_file is same as shown sample, if yes then following may help you.

```
awk '
{
  flag=flag2=""
  for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i ~ /41572/ || $i ~ /90000/ || $i ~ /90002/){
       flag2++
       if(flag2==1){
           printf("%s %s : ",$1,$2)
       }
       flag=1
       printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)
    }
  }
}
!flag
'   Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation too here for above code.

```
awk '                                                     ##Starting awk script here.
{                                                         ##Starting main block from here when Input_file is being read.
  flag=flag2=""                                           ##Nullifying variables named flag and flag2 here.
  for(i=3;i<=NF;i++){                                     ##Starting a for loop from i value from 3 to NF value in current line.
    if($i ~ /41572/ || $i ~ /90000/ || $i ~ /90002/){     ##Checking condition if any fields value is having keywords mentioned by OP or not.
       flag2++                                            ##Increment variable flag2 here with one.
       if(flag2==1){                                      ##If flag2 value is 1 then print 1st and 2nd column value here.
           printf("%s %s : ",$1,$2)
       }
       flag=1                                             ##Setting variable named flag value to 1 here.
       printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?ORS:OFS)                    ##Printing value of current field along with check of if i==NF then print new line else print OFS.
    }
  }
}
!flag                                                     ##Checking condition here if !flag then print the current line.
'  Input_file                                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```